# SoapUI JSON Path assertion for two different strings not using JsonSlurper

Tags: json, soapui, assertion, jsonpath

I'm using SoapUI JSONPath Mach feature to assert JSON Response. Depend on a language, I can have two different responses:

`Factura no encontrada en el lote.` or `Invoice not found in open batch.`

I know I can do this using JsonSlurper:

```
assert jsonSlurper.header.rspMsg in ["Factura no encontrada en el lote.","Invoice not found in open batch."]
```

But, what I'm looking for is to use this in SoapUI assertion feature, see screenshot:
[image]

Specifically, how should I change bottom:

```
"Factura no encontrada en el lote." OR "Invoice not found in open batch."
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible using `JSONPath match assert` (at least with existing versions, maybe in the future...). For this asserts in expected result only strings are allowed (or expand expression which will be evaluated to strings) , so it's not possible to set the expected values using `OR` operator as you want to do.

An alternative way to do it could be to put the `OR` operator in jsonpath expression an use `true` as expected result.

For example for your case you can using something like:

`$.header.[?(@.['rspMsg'] == 'Factura no encontrada en el lote.' || ?(@.['rspMsg'] == 'Invoice not found in open batch.']`

And in the expected result use `true`.

However there is already another problem, SOAPUI 5.2.1 use [`com.jayway.jsonpath`](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath) version 0.9.1 and this version doesn't support `||` operator, so this doesn't work.

So the last attempt could be to use `JSONPath Regex match assert` which evaluates the JSONPath expression against a provided regex and expects true or false. Using this approach you can use:

*JSONPath expression:* `$.header.rspMsg`

*Regular expression:* `(Factura no encontrada en el lote\.)|(Invoice not found in open batch\.)`

*Expected result:* `true`

[image]

At this point I think that the better approach is yours using `jsonSlurper` to perform the assertion.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks for such a thorough answer, I was thinking to use RegEx but couldn't figure out the pattern, anyway I think using JsonSlurper here is much better approach.

Comment: @QB1979 regex is the best approach I found to fit your requerimentes... but of course your first approach is much better `:)`.